# How to make smaller points on a Silverlight Toolkit's LineChart?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, charts, silverlight-toolkit

By default if you take a look at the Silverlight toolkit demo site,

http://silverlight.net/content/samples/sl3/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html

you will see on the LineChart some points which are relatively big.

As far as I know every point on the Chart is an Ellipse.
For that I created the style on xaml file.

```
  <Style x:Name="ChartLineBar" TargetType="Ellipse">
       <Setter Property="Width" Value="10"/>
       <Setter Property="Height" Value="10"/> 
   </Style>
```

and bind like this:

```
series.DataPointStyle = Resources["ChartLineBar"] as Style;
```

This did not work, so after that I decided to like that:
I basically recreate the structure which are showing the points.

```
       <Style x:Name="ChartLineBar" TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root">
                        <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Visibility="Visible" Opacity="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

This did not work either, but I think that there should exist a solution for that because, if I use the SilverlightSpy, I can access all the properties and if I modify there the point's size is decreasing.
How can I make smaller points on a silverlight LineChart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The July 09 source code shows the default width and height to be 8 so I'm not sure setting them to 10 would make them smaller.

Have you tried it like this:-

```
<Style x:Name="ChartLineBar" TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="10"/> 
</Style>
```

Note that the TargetType is LineDataPoint.

Comment: This is working,i tried this solution first,but obviously a made a mistake there.Thanks!